# remove bouncing from PhysicsBody?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

How can I completely remove the bounciness from my PhysicsBodies, I already set the restitution of all PhysicsBodies to 0 but when multiple PhysicsBodies collide they still bounce off of each other, how can turn this off?
Here's a video where i swipe up and down which triggers this code on the blue SpriteNodes:

```
node.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: x, dy: y))
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wugbK.jpg

I want the blue SpriteNodes to just stay up or down and not bounce away

Comment: So, do you want to model absolutely inelastic collisions or what?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want, how do I do that?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody/1520447-restitution) zero restitution models absolutely _elastic_ collision. You want unit restitution.

Comment: When I set restitution to 1 then they just bounce non-stop and if I set it to 0 then that happens what i described in my Question, so does that mean it's not possible to make what I want since restitution is the only thing that alters bounciness?

Comment: Well, Apple's docs are notorious for their comprehensiveness. I'd guess that your problem might be not in the elasticity then. Consider providing some source code fragments and/or video demonstrations. Improve your question 

Comment: edited my question

Comment: I had an error with the same thing. I actually spoke with a few Apple engineers over the summer at WWDC, and there is probably an error with Apple’s physics engine because no one on the team could help me fix it. I filed a radar. You should too.

Comment: So there is no way to make what I want at the moment?

Comment: Looking at your video I'm wondering whether you control the parameters of the screen/scene boundaries — they can still be elastic (though, it wouldn't explain everything).

Comment: The top and bottom black borders are also PhysicsBodies with restitution set to 0, it‘s really weird.

Comment: Without code we can't be sure that it is not a problem inside it.

Comment: What else would you need except the restitution?

Answer (score 0):

Are you experimenting in a space without any world damping/friction? If so, you will need to zero the velocity of objects the moment they collide in order to get zero bounce. But you'll also need to move them outside the boundary of the objects they collided with.

By way of explanation:
This is, I presume, happening because your objects are achieving a (slight) state of overlap right before the collision is reported to the physics engine. When this happens, the first response of some physics engines is to remove this overlap by moving the object with a corrective amount of force or movement. What's happening looks like a continuation of that movement.

In some physics engines you get the opportunity to determine how strongly the corrective behaviour is, and how frequently it occurs, and even set the physics simulation to much higher rates of solving than the frame rate. In these engines you could find the right balance of settings to prevent this. But not in SpriteKit.

Comment: Do you have any code to how I could move them outside the boundary of the objects they collide with?